# WooCommerce redirect to product category on add to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to redirect a user to previous category page when he clicks on Add to Cart on product page. But on redirect I am seeing a blank product_cat attribute. i.e. `example.com/?product_cat=`
However if I echo it to `woocommerce_product_thumbnail` it shows the link perfectly. i.e. `example.com/?product_cat=shoes`

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_previousCat');
//add_filter ('woocommerce_product_thumbnails', 'redirect_to_previousCat');
function redirect_to_previousCat() {
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    $product_cat_slug;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
    $product_cat_slug = $term->slug;
    break;
}
$url=get_site_url().'?product_cat='.$product_cat_slug;
return $url;
}
```

Comment: did you try to `print_r($post);`? see if it has value...

Comment: @Reigel yes, it has values on woocommerce_product_thumbnails I tested it with print_r($url)

Comment: I don't actually think that `$post` is set up yet. The add to cart form handler action runs on `init`. You can `die(var_dump($post));` in the `add_to_cart_redirect()` filter to see this. The `woocommerce_product_thumbnails()` runs much later after `$post` is set up. By the way, what is `$product_cat_slug`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, the global `$post` is not set up yet when the `add_to_cart_action()` method runs on the `init` hook.

Instead, I suggest you follow Wootheme's lead and get the product ID from the `$_REQUEST` global.

```
add_filter ('add_to_cart_redirect', 'redirect_to_previousCat');

function redirect_to_previousCat( $url ) {
    $product_id = absint( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] );
    $product_cat_slug = '';

    $terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $product_cat_slug = $term->slug;
        break;
    }
    if( $product_cat_slug ){
        $url = add_query_arg( 'product_cat', $product_cat_slug, site_url() );
    }
    return $url;
}
```